# Add an image by using HTML in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7

I have one problem about how to add an image by using HTML in Windows Phone 7

school

```
    <Image Name="myImg" Source="/WindowsPhoneApplication14;component/Images/Assets/about_school.jpg"

           align="left" width="170" height="200"/>
    <b>Little Flower Public School:</b><br/><br/>
    Little Flower Public School, At Little Flowers, learning is a joyful experience. Children are molded into confident
    and compassionate individuals, giving them the edge to span the horizon with élan.

    The system of education cannot remain static. The School endeavors to prepare children for a world which is becoming
    more and more complex by the day. The emphasis is on all round development through a process of probing, questioning
    and analyzing.

    The State of the Art architecture of the School building designed by M/s. Thomas Architects and M/s. Mitresh
    Architects provides spacious and well ventilated class rooms, three science laboratories, 2 libraries, Computer
    Room, Audio Visual Room, Amphitheatre and lung space for recreational activities.
    -----------------------------------
    The administrative and teaching facilities are spread over six levels.

    Learning amidst fun and frolic is the mantra of Pre-school education today. The Kindergarten at Little Flower Public
    School is the stepping stone into the world of What, When, Where, Who, Why................

    At Little Flowers, learning is a joyful experience. Children are moulded into confident and compassionate
    individuals, giving them the edge to span the horizon with élan.<br/><br/>
    <br/>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above HTML listing, All the content is displayed except the image. Could you please  tell me how to insert an image source?

Answer (score 2):

`<Image>` is not HTML. The correct tag name is `<img>` and its source is attribute `src`:

```
<img src="somepicture.jpg">
```